# error reading text file; lines read twice and with every other having extra line break

Tags: c, file-io

I'm reading a text file (written on a UNIX or Linux machine) that is supposed to have one entry on each line. When I read it with my program and output the file contents to the console every other entry has an extra line break and each line is repeated twice. Here is the code

```
FILE* fullList;
char sline[21];
fullList = fopen("fullList", "r");
if(fullList == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
while(fgets(sline, sizeof(sline), fullList) != NULL)
{
    puts(sline);
    printf(sline);
}
fclose(fullList);
```

So if the input file contains

```
apple
banana
orange
zucchini
cucumber
eggplant
```

the program would display it as

```
apple

apple
banana

banana
orange

orange
zucchini

zucchini
cucumber

cucumber
eggplant
eggplant
```

I'm not sure what's doing it. Must I some how clear sline before using it again?

Comment: Note that using `printf(sline)` is danerous if `sline` contains any `%` symbols, you are very vulnerable to crashing as `printf()` tries to access arguments you didn't pass to it.  Use: `printf("%s", sline)` instead; that's safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you print each line twice - once through puts, and once through printf.

`fgets` captures newline `\n`, and `puts` appends a `'\n'` of its own, so there's an additional line break after the first printout.

The last line in the file (`"eggplant"`) lacks the trailing `'\n'`, so there's no extra blank line in between the two eggplant printouts.

To fix this problem, first stop calling one of the printing functions. Next, make sure that the line you read does not have a `\n` at the end. You could either strip it off yourself, or use

```
while (fscanf(fulllist, "%20s", sline) == 1) {
    ...
}
```

It is not advisable to call `printf` with your string in the spot of the formal parameter, because having unexpected format symbols there may lead to undefined behavior. If you decide to use `printf`, use it as follows:

```
printf("%s\n", sline);
```

Comment: Strange I got rid of the `fputs()` and it fixed everything, including the extra line breaks.

Comment: @Celeritas There should be no line break after the last line (i.e. eggplant), right?

Answer (score 3):

What do you think this does?

```
puts(sline);
printf(sline);
```

The first one prints the line (followed by a newline!).  The second one prints the line, but formats anything starting with % in a special way.  So `puts()` gives you an extra newline, but `printf()` is even worse--look up the documentation and think about what would happen if your file contains "%s" or "%d".

So you want to use only a single output statement, and you don't want double newlines.  You could remove the newline from each line before printing, but even better is to use `fputs(sline, stdout)` which does not add a newline.

As an aside, a bit of advice: using C to process text files is going to be pretty painful for you (as a newcomer to C).  I suggest using some other language, such as Python, Ruby, awk, sed, or anything else based on your needs and experience.